# Implementing Read-Only

Tags: c#

I have to implement a read-only for my Description field, which I only have a get statement. When I'm trying to write to the array list description it doesn't let me since its only getter I have. As seen below trying to do in my main.

I tried writing a constructor but get error message get have method groups when trying to add to array list.

```
static void Main(string[] args)

 grocery.Add(new GroceryItem { Description="4L Milk" Price = 3.87M, ExpirationDate= DateTime.Now });

Class Grocerypackage
 public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
        }
```

Comment: Your code is full of unrelated errors, which makes it hard to answer your question. I cannot imagine this being typed in an IDE, and if not, please post actual code, not just a rough description of it.

Comment: Well that is what readonly is meant to do. Add a constructor to your `GroceryPackage` that takes a description as parameter. In the constructor you can assign to the readonly property to initialize it.

Comment: This will not allow me to set description to constructor since its only gets a getter. public GroceryPackage (string description)
        {
            Description = description;
        }

Comment: Your class does not contain a member named `description` and you could define a `private` or `protected` setter if you want one that is only accessible from within the class

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var groceries = new List<GroceryItem>();
            groceries.Add(new GroceryItem("Carrot", 23.57m, DateTime.Today));
        }
    }

    internal sealed class GroceryItem
    {
        public GroceryItem(string description, decimal price, DateTime expirationDate)
        {
            Description = description;
            Price = price;
            ExpirationDate = expirationDate;
        }
        public string Description { get; }
        public decimal Price { get; }
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; }
    }
}
```

In C#, you can initialise readonly fields in the constructor. You could also use `private set`. Then the GroceryItem class can acess the `setter`. e.g.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var gi = new GroceryItem("Carrot");
            gi.Foo();

            Console.WriteLine(gi.Description);
        }
    }

    internal class GroceryItem
    {
        public GroceryItem(string description)
        {
            Description = description;   // We can set this in ctor
        }
        public string Description { get; private set; }

        public void Foo()
        {
            Description = "Foo";
        }
    }
```

You could also use a backing field with the readonly keyword

```
internal class GroceryItem
    {
        private readonly string _description;
        public GroceryItem(string description)
        {
            _description = description;   // We can set this in ctor
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `private set` instead of `protected set`.

Comment: You are correct :)